# ConfigurationManager doesn't save settings to exe.config

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, configuration, app-config

(My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216809/configurationmanager-doesnt-save-settings), but the code is slightly different, and the solution doesn't work for me)

I'm trying to save settings changes to the `app.config`:

```
Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
config.AppSettings.Settings("HistoryRootDirectoryPath").Value = p_historySavingPath
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
```

Nothing is saved neither to the `exe.config` file in bin folder, and not to the actual `app.config` file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Exceptions? Have you looked at both the `Debug` and `Release` folders?

Comment: @Oded: Checked both debug and release, no exception been thrown.

Comment: I've found it being saved in "**.vshost.exe.config"

Comment: Ah. Because the code is being run under the Visual Studio process host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally ended finding the changes are being saved under **.vshost.exe.config**.

As [Oded](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) mentioned,that is because the code is being run under the Visual Studio process host.

Note that the changes are being reverted once you stop the process run.