# In VB.net, how do I save changes to app.config

Tags: vb.net, app-config, appsettings

I have a couple of appSettings in my app.config file, with default values:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Foo" value="one"/>
  <add key="Bar" value="two"/>
</appSettings>
```

which I am able to read and put the values into a TextBox and a ComboBox

I have this code to save the changes made to those two, but the changes I make are not saved to the app.config file itself, so when I close the program and open it again, the values go back to the defaults.

```
Private Sub ButtonSaveSettings_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSaveSettings.Click
    Dim settings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

    settings.Set("Foo", TextBoxFoo.Text)
    settings.Set("Bar", ComboBoxBar.SelectedItem.ToString)
End Sub
```

What do I need to do to get the updated values to persist to the app.config file?

(edit: The answers on the duplicate were not for VB and didn't solve this issue.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ConfigurationManager doesn't save settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216809/configurationmanager-doesnt-save-settings)

Comment: The answers there didn't help. But I've figured it out now, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't need to mess around with the ConfirgurationManager by changing my app.config file to this (using Solution Explorer -> My Project -> Settings)

```
<userSettings>
    <MyProject.My.MySettings>
        <setting name="Foo" serializeAs="String">
            <value>one</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="Bar" serializeAs="String">
            <value>two</value>
        </setting>
    </MyProject.My.MySettings>
</userSettings>
```

I was able to use this code to save the updated values for my settings

```
Private Sub ButtonSaveSettings_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSaveSettings.Click
    My.Settings.Foo = TextBoxFoo.Text
    My.Settings.Bar = ComboBoxBar.SelectedItem.ToString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Another method would be to use

```
My.Settings.Save()
```

In your ButtonSaveSettings.Click Event. Otherwise, the settings would not be retentive

Answer (score 2):

the options above is for setting not for app settings keys.
I had the same problem and I solved it with the following code

```
    Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

    config.AppSettings.Settings("yourKeyName").Value = YourNewValue        
    
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified) 

    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
```

it is very important to save changes!!!
refresh is optional (RefreshSection), if you need to immediately use the updated values